# How to validate form input text with javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm trying to create a form with different inputs, input validation error receiving text, it does not validate (I want to be just text). The code is:

```
<form action="" id="myform" name="checkform" onsubmit="return validateform()" method="post">
    <label for='Name'>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
    <label for='Surname'>Surname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="surname" ><br> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The javascript is:

```
   function validateform(){     
    if(document.checkform.name.value == ""){
        window.alert("Please insert your name.");
            document.checkform.name.focus();
            return false;
    }
    var nameText = document.forms["myform"]["name"].value; /* here is the problem :-( */
    if (!name.match(/^\s*[A-Za-z]+\s*$/)) {
    alert("Insert just letters !!!");
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You create a variable `nameText` and then on the next line say `name.match()` - it should be `nameText.match()`. Why are you using `document.checkform.name.value` first and then `document.forms["myform"]["name"].value` to reference the _same_ field? Pick a syntax and stick with it.

Comment: `<input type="text" name="name" pattern="/[a-zA-Z]+/" required>` (+ polyfill for non-html5 browsers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function validateform() {
  var nameTxtBx = document.checkform.name,
    name = nameTxtBx.value; //<-- added this line
  if (name == "") {
    alert("Please insert your name.");
    nameTxtBx.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (!name.match(/^\s*[A-Za-z]+\s*$/)) {
    alert("trebue doar litere");
    return false;
  }
  return true; //<-- added this line
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="myform" name="checkform" onsubmit="return validateform()" method="post">
  <label for='Name'>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <br>
  <label for='Surname'>Surname:</label>
  <input type="text" name="surname">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @pascarel, I am glad it helped you, you may accept my answer as it worked for you ....

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in your variable, You just rename your variable `nameText` into `name` or vice versa.

```
 var nameText = document.forms["myform"]["name"].value;
     ^^^^^^^  
 if (!name.match(/^\s*[A-Za-z]+\s*$/)) {
      ^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Named form controls are made members of the form using their name. So even though the form has a *name* property, because your form also has a control with a name of *name*, then `form.name` references the control, not the form's *name* property.

Similarly, having a control with a name of *submit* means that you can't call the form's *submit* method, because *form.submit* references the control, not the method. So you should use control names that don't clash with standard form properties. Also, it's rare to require an ID for form controls since they can be referenced as properties of the form.

Lastly, it is handy to pass a reference to the form from the listener using *this*, then you don't need an ID on the form either. Consider:

```
<form onsubmit="return validateform(this)" ... >
    Name: <input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
    Surname: <input type="text" name="surname"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then in the function:

```
function validateform(form) {
```

Get the value of the *firstName* control once:

```
  var firstName = form.firstName.value;
```

Now do the tests:

```
  if (firstName == "") {
    window.alert("Please insert your first name.");
    form.firstName.focus();
    return false;
  }
```

It's more appropriate to use *test* than *match* if you want to test for a pattern rather than find all the matches:

```
  if (!/^\s*[A-Za-z]+\s*$/.test(firstName)) {
    alert("Insert just letters !!!");
    return false;
  }
}
```